# mysql group by organize results

Tags: mysql, group-by

First of all, I'm not aware if I named the question correctly but I do not know how to call it correctly :/

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( id ), jumper, `date` FROM demosdb WHERE jumperid = '1053' GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY  `COUNT(id)` DESC
```

basically `demosdb` is:

```
id (int), jumperid (int), date (int (basically contains timestamp))
```

So far, so good. But, there's slight difference between some records (I use an automatic script to update, and sometimes it sets the time +/-5s, e.g. the result of that query:

```
COUNT(id)   date
10  1318763642
10  1318763643
10  1318763639
9   1318763641
9   1318763637
8   1318763640
8   1366200434
```

You can see the first rows have almost the same time, but 5s difference (37 to 42). It is 100% sure that +/-60s (and even more) is part of the same thing, so I want to basically group all the timestamps which are not `1234567890` but `12345678%`. Is that possible with mysql only, or should I rely on php?

Comment: Your problem is not well defined: you could have a long series of records that differ 5s each other but with 1 hour of difference between the first one and the last one. How would you group them?

Comment: @Pino I think the implication in Nikola's question is that that cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do something with `ROUND` and a negative rounding value, which will round to the left of the decimal rather than the right. For example, the dates in your results will look like this if you use `ROUND(date, -1)`:

```
date        round(date, -1)
----------  ---------------
1318763642  1318763640
1318763643  1318763640
1318763639  1318763640
1318763641  1318763640
1318763637  1318763640
1318763640  1318763640
1366200434  1366200430
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping in SQL is purely reliant on identical values, not near or similar. You could probably hack this by grouping by `date/60` to group blocks of minutes together, but then you'd still have a threshold problem (something on the 60th second would be in a different block than something on the first second of the next minute). As such I'd definitely recommend doing this in PHP with a smarter algorithm, comparing all rows and closing a block when there's a gap of more than 10 or 20 seconds with the previous one.

Having said that, your query is bugged. When using `GROUP BY` all columns that are NOT grouped should have an aggregate function (such as `max` or `avg`) to tell the DBMS *how* to group them. In your case you haven't done this for column `jumper`, so it will essentially contain random results (although often appearing logical). MySQL is the only DBMS which historically allows this, while it is a fatal query error in all other database servers. MySQL supports a strict mode these days that does consider it an error, and you *should definitely* assume this behaviour to become default in the future. As such you should change it now to prevent breaking in the future.

Something like this would work:

```
$threshold = 60;
$results = [];
$block = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
  if($row->date - $block > $threshold)
    $block = $row->date;
  $results[$block] += $row->count; 
}
```

(pardon me for using deprecated `mysql_` command, it's easiest for quick pseudocode)

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the potential flaws highlighted nearby , the alternative solution might look like this...

```
SELECT FLOOR(date/60)*60 dt
     , COUNT(DISTINCT jumperid) ttl 
  FROM jumpers 
 GROUP 
    BY dt;
```